# Need to compare sql database cell value (date) to date in DateTime picker

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to compare( before or after) a database cell value containing date (in dd/MM/yyyy format) to a date in DateTime Picker in ASP.net.

can any one help me??

```
string str2 = "select ITEM,INSTALLMENT,AMOUNT from Class_Fee where CLASS='" + classdrop.SelectedItem + "' and S_DATE>'" + feedate .SelectedDate   +"' ";
```

Comment: Please use SQL Parameters to prevent [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)!

Comment: I also suggest storing your values in an appropiately typed database column, such as datetime(2), or date depending on your needs. See [Date and Time Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733.aspx) for options in MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the `DateTime` value from DB using `dataRow1` in for loop, convert the achieved result to string  using `ToString()` and then use the following : `DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", 0);` and then compare it with the value of the ASP.net page